# Swift trouble with operator priority

Tags: swift, operators, operator-precedence

**UPDATED**

Expression: `a ?? 0 + b`, where `a` is `CGFloat?`, `b` is `CGFloat` and `a != nil`.

Concrete example:

```
//a == 99
//b == 253
let t = ((a ?? 0) + b)
let t2 = (a ?? 0 + b)
//t == 352
//t2 == 99
```

Why the result is correct if I set brackets only: `(a ?? 0) + b`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both results are “correct.” They can be different because `+` has a higher precedence than `??`. In particular, if `a != nil`:

```
 t  == (a ?? 0) + b == a! + b
 t2 == (a ?? 0 + b) == a ?? (0 + b) == a!
```

The complete list of operator precedences can be found at [Operator Declarations](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/swift_standard_library/operator_declarations).